# PySpark: Check if value from one column matches another on next row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a data frame listed as follows:

```
StartTime   StartName   StopTime    StopName
10.00       A           11.00       B
11.00       B           13.00       C
14.00       D           17.00       A
```

And I would like to filter out where the **StartName** column on one row equals the **StopName** column on the next row. I'm hoping to create a new data frame as follows:

```
StartTime   StartName   StopTime    StopName
13.00       C           14.00       D
```

I'm a bit lost, I've tried using window but couldn't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Window` works: you can add the `StopName` of the prevoius row as new column to each row and then filter out according to your requirement:

```python
w = Window.orderBy("StartTime").rowsBetween(-1,-1)
df = ...
df = df.withColumn("PrevStopName", F.lag("StopName").over(w))
df = df.filter("StartName <> PrevStopName").drop("PrevStopName")
```

As the window definition does not include a partition, the warning

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

will appear.

To prevent the performance problem, the input data should also contain a grouping column that groups together all rows that should be considered together in the window operation. This column should then be used as parameter of `Window.partitionBy`.